# Add a Youtube embed video on Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: windows, video, youtube, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video into my Windows 10 Universal App. I know there is ways to do it that goes against the terms on YouTube, but is there a way to do this that doesn't go against them?

I've tried the following code, and I was able to get a YouTube player up. But the video doesn't load.

Under Initialize

```
string html = @"<style> body{margin:0; padding:0;} iframe{width:100%;height:480px;}@media screen and (max-width:300px) { iframe{width:100%;height:180px;}}  </style><iframe style=""padding:0px;margin-bottom:-20px;""   src=""https://www.youtube.com/embed/OLE5oAZanA4" + @" ? rel=0"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        videoView.NavigateToString(html);
```

UI code

```
<WebView Name="videoView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="297" Margin="466,150,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441"/>
```

For anyone that does use MyToolkit (which goes against YT terms). Is the views still being tracked when you use this method?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
StringBuilder stringbuild = new StringBuilder();
        stringbuild.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        stringbuild.Append("<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
        stringbuild.Append("<head> <meta charset=\"utf-8\"/> <title></title> </head>");
        stringbuild.Append("<body>");
        stringbuild.Append(" <style>  iframe {border: none;}");
        stringbuild.Append(" html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden;} </style>");
        stringbuild.Append(" <div id=\"player\" style=\"width:200px; height:400px;\"></div>");
        stringbuild.Append("<script>");
        stringbuild.Append("var tag = document.createElement('script');");
        stringbuild.Append("tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";");
        stringbuild.Append("var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];");
        stringbuild.Append(" firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);");
        stringbuild.Append(" function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {window.external.notify(\"YoutubePlayerLoadCompleted\");  }");
        stringbuild.Append(" var width; var height;");
        stringbuild.Append(" function setwidth(incoming) { width = incoming; document.getElementById(\"player\").style.width = incoming+ 'px';  }");
        stringbuild.Append("function setheight(incoming) { height = incoming; document.getElementById(\"player\").style.height = incoming +'px';    }");
        stringbuild.Append("var player;");
        stringbuild.Append(" function loadplayer(incomming) {  player = new YT.Player('player', {   height: height,  width: width,  playerVars: { 'fs': 1 }, videoId: incomming,   events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } });   var element = document.getElementById('videoframe'); }");
        stringbuild.Append("function onPlayerReady(event) { }");
        stringbuild.Append("function onPlayerStateChange(event) {}");
        stringbuild.Append("function play() { if (!player){} else { try { player.playVideo();} catch(err){window.external.notify(err.message);} }}");
        stringbuild.Append(" function pause() { player.pauseVideo(); }");
        stringbuild.Append("</script> </body> </html>");
        string ts = stringbuild.ToString();

        webview.NavigateToString(ts);

        webview.ScriptNotify += async delegate (object sender1, NotifyEventArgs e1)
        {
            var jsScriptValue = e1.Value;
            if (jsScriptValue.ToString().Equals("YoutubePlayerLoadCompleted"))
            {

                await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("setwidth", new string[] {"500" });
                await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("setheight", new string[] {"400" });
                await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("loadplayer", new string[] { "_P9lGTiiXW0" });

            }

        };
```